# how to solve ConcurrentModificationException thrown by my android program?

Tags: java, android, exception

I am accessing default location of sdcard where images are stored after capturing. I am doing so in background service. But as soon as camera is opened, exception is being thrown called ConcurrentModificationException()

```
String absPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString()+"/100MEDIA/";
File folder = new File(absPath);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles.length; j++) {
    if (listOfFiles[j].isFile()) {
        temp.add(listOfFiles[j].getName());
    } 
}
```

This is my code in which I am creating list of images in dcim folde. What is causing exception and how to solve it?

Comment: You're adding to `temp` list on this worker thread, my guess is you're doing something else with `temp` on main thread.

Comment: The stack trace or at least the message that comes with the exception might help.

Comment: Thank you for responding. After your comment, I checked my code and found that I was creating threads  in while loop and thus every thread was trying to access temp variable. I solved it by using static variable to control creation of new threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is not thrown by this code.

Indeed, the only way that this code could be "caused" by this code would be if you executed it while another thread was iterating the `temp` collection.

Comment: Thank you for responding. After your comment, I checked my code and found that I was creating threads in while loop and thus every thread was trying to access temp variable. I solved it by using static variable to control creation of new threads.